# SQL0107N The name "insert into OH09ZC1.cte3 with cte2 (list, cnt, cnt_max) AS (SELECT" is too long. The maximum length is "128"

Tags: db2

Here is the procedure where I use a statement with temp table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dept_query (
    p_table        CHAR(10), 
    p_date         CHAR(10),
p_start        CHAR(6) 
)
    LANGUAGE SQL

BEGIN
DECLARE        v_table         VARCHAR(128);
DECLARE        v_colname       VARCHAR(128);
DECLARE      v_month            CHAR(6);
DECLARE      v_int          integer default 0;
DECLARE        stat       VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE stmt STATEMENT;
.......
set stat = 'insert into cte1 select colname, row_number() over() as row_nbr from syscat.columns where tabname = ?';
PREPARE stmt FROM stat;
execute stmt using p_table;

set stat = "insert into  OH09ZC1.cte3  -- cte, cte1 & cte3 are ordinary tables
    with cte2 (list, cnt, cnt_max) AS 
    (SELECT VARCHAR('', 32000), 0, count(colname) FROM OH09ZC1.cte1
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT 
         case when cte2.list = '' THEN RTRIM(CHAR(cte1.colname)) 
              else cte2.list || ', ' || RTRIM(CHAR(cte1.colname)) end, 
              cte2.cnt + 1, 
              cte2.cnt_max 
     FROM   OH09ZC1.cte1, cte2 
     WHERE  cte1.row_nbr = cte2.cnt + 1 AND cte2.cnt < cte2.cnt_max ) 

select list FROM cte2 where cte2.cnt = cte2.cnt_max fetch first 1 rows only"; 

PREPARE stmt FROM stat;
execute stmt;
......
END;
```

This gets me a list of the columns in a table.
The problem is that 'insert into  OH09ZC1.cte3 with cte2 (list, cnt, cnt_max) AS ' doesn't contain any long names, so why do I get this error:
SQL0107N  The name "insert into  OH09ZC1.cte3 with cte2 (list, cnt, cnt_max) AS (SELEC" is too long.  The maximum length is "128".
I also got the same error when 'insert into  OH09ZC1.cte3' was not there.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Rowland Shaw DB2 v10.1.0.2

Answer (score 1):

`set stat = "insert into...` -- SQL string literals should use single quotation marks. Double quotation marks indicate an identifier, and `"insert into cte3 ..."`, in addition to being too long for an identifier, is invalid anyway.

Comment: Great. Just what should I do with the single quotation marks within the statement?

Comment: Got it, use 2 single quotation marks instead of one for quotes within the statement. Thanks.